# Inserting into SQL Server table - data would be truncated (URL Related?)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working on a project for class where I'm creating a fan portal for people interested in creators of image comics. I'm trying to use a SQL Server database as the source of my information and when someone clicks a URL it will populate a MVC view page with the information about that creator from the SQL Table. I was currently making the table but I ran into trouble, I cannot seem to insert into the table I have made.

This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Writers]
(
    [WriterID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [WriterLast] CHAR(20) NULL, 
    [WriterFirst] CHAR(20) NULL, 
    [WriterBio] CHAR(500) NULL, 
    [WriterBorn] CHAR(18) NULL, 
    [WriterPastSeries] CHAR(30) NULL, 
    [WriterWebsite] CHAR(50) NULL, 
    [WriterTwitter] CHAR(50) NULL, 
    [WriterFacebook] CHAR(50) NULL
)
```

And here is the insert statement I am trying to use:

```
INSERT INTO Writers
VALUES (101, 'Brubaker', 'Ed', 'Ed Brubaker (born November 17, 1966) is an American comic book writer and cartoonist. Brubaker''s first early comics work was primarily in the crime fiction genre with works such as Lowlife, The Fall, Sandman Presents: Dead Boy Detectives and Scene of the Crime. He later became known for writing superhero comics such as Batman, Daredevil, Captain America, Catwoman, Uncanny X-Men, and The Authority. He has won an Eisner Award on six separate occasions. (Wikipedia)', 'Bethesda, MD', 'Batman, Daredevil, Captain America, Uncanny X-Men', 'https://imagecomics.com/creators/view/ed-brubaker', 'NO TWITTER', 'NO FACEBOOK');
```

The error I am getting is:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

Any advice?

Comment: This means that you are trying to insert a string with a longer length than the data type in your table. The question is simple to ask it here.

Comment: Side issue but related to the affected field: Is the writer to series relationship one-to-many or many-to-many? Is it a ternary relationship with time? You've jammed many series into one field. Think about people being interested in everything about a series, especially one with more than one writer at a time or even over time. (It's a bit tough to get started but consider [NORMA](https://www.ormfoundation.org/files/folders/normalabs/default.aspx).)

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for advice.

First, do not use `char()` use `varchar()`.  It is ridiculous to take up all the space in the data for spaces at the end of strings.

Second, the bio is probably not long enough.  Choose either `varchar(8000)` or `varchar(max)`.  The former is the longest "non-infinite" string supported by SQL Server.  The latter is basically unlimited length (well, not quite, but good enough for most purposes).

In addition, other columns should be longer.  I would suggest making everything `varchar(8000)` or `nvarchar(8000)` or `nvarchar(max)` -- after all, you might get non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: `char` probably does not have an ASCII collation but even so, `nvarchar` would eliminate character set concerns. Hergé. René Goscinny.

Answer (score 0):

WriterPastSeries are 49 chars and should be 30.